# Onclick function in WhatsApp button

Tags: javascript, html

I have onclick function in the order button that sends input to the database , after modifying the button (connecting it to WhatsApp instead of database) `onclick` function has stopped working...  I need that `onclick` function to work.

```html
<form className="orderForm">
    <div className="form-group">
        <div className="whatsapp" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <button
                className="btn-primary"
                onClick="reportConversion(event.target)"
                type="submit"
                style="height:70px;width: 100%;"
            >
                <img
                    src="wat.png"
                    style="width: 36px;height: 36px; position: absolute; margin-left: -40px;margin-top: -10px;"
                />
                <a href="https://wa.me/......" style="color: white;font-weight: 600; font-size: 18px;">
                    ...text...
                </a>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use `window.location.href` after `reportConversion()` returns any result.

Comment: like this onclick="reportConversion(event.target)"+window.location.href ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a nice solution to use a `Promse`, but the `reportConversion` return is unknown, also not sure we can modify it?

Anyways, as we have the link priority, this solution would probably fit.

Notice: remember to change the `<button>` type from `submit` to `button` and remove the link from the inside.

```js
function reportConversionWrapper(target) {
  reportConversion(target);
  setTimeout( function() {
    window.location.href = 'https://wa.me/......';
  }, 1000 );
}
// following is just a filler - don't mind it
function reportConversion(a) {
  return;
}
```

```html
<form className="orderForm">
    <div className="form-group">
        <div className="whatsapp" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <button
                className="btn-primary"
                onclick="reportConversionWrapper(event.target)"
                type="button"
                style="height:70px;width: 100%;"
            >
                <img
                    src="wat.png"
                    style="width: 36px;height: 36px; position: absolute; margin-left: -40px;margin-top: -10px;"
                />...text...
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```